# CSS FontFamily for Spark FormItems

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, actionscript, flex4, flex4.6

Hi im sure this is an easy one and im just missing something ive been having a lot of trouble with mx and spark components looking the same and using a custom font, here is my css

```
@font-face {
src: url("/resources/styles/fonts/MyriadWebPro.ttf");
fontFamily: MyriadWebPro;
fontWeight: normal;
embedAsCFF: false;
unicodeRange: U+0041-U+005A, 
    U+0061-U+007A, 
    U+0030-U+0039, 
    U+0020-U+002F, 
    U+003A-U+0040, 
    U+005B-U+0060, 
    U+007B-U+007E;
}
@font-face {
src: url("/resources/styles/fonts/MyriadWebPro.ttf");
fontFamily: MyriadWebProCFF;
fontWeight: normal;
embedAsCFF: true;
unicodeRange: U+0041-U+005A, 
    U+0061-U+007A, 
    U+0030-U+0039, 
    U+0020-U+002F, 
    U+003A-U+0040, 
    U+005B-U+0060, 
    U+007B-U+007E;
}

s|TextInput
{
contentBackgroundColor: #FFFFFF;
fontFamily: MyriadWebProCFF;
}
s|Label
{
fontFamily: MyriadWebProCFF;
color: #00FFFF;
}
s|FormItem s|Label#labelDisplay {
fontFamily: MyriadWebProCFF;
}
```

please can some tell me what im doing wrong as the color changes correctly but the font doesnt?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possible case for not embedding a font to a application.

- check a path of Custom font.
- embedding a Bold font and using a fontweight="normal" as default.
- Embedded fonts have anti-aliased = true/false;
- check  embedAsCFF: true; Property for the component on which you apply a font
- Please don't ignore any warning regard font embedding otherwise not effected.

refer this link for [Information about embedding a Font](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=fonts_04.html) and [Troubleshooting fonts in applications](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/flex/using/WS2db454920e96a9e51e63e3d11c0bf6320a-7fec.html)

May this link will be helpful!